# Abrir una ventana al oprimir una tecla en un JFrame

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, keypressevent

Estoy tratando de abrir una ventana al oprimir la tecla escape, tengo el siguiente código que funciona, pero abre 2 ventanas y no he podido hacer que abra sólo una.

```
KeyboardFocusManager kb = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
    kb.addKeyEventPostProcessor(new KeyEventPostProcessor() {
        @Override
        public boolean postProcessKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("EVENTO : postProcessKeyEvent");
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE && this != null) {
                System.out.println("SE TECLEÓ ESC");
                if (validarFaturacion()) {
                    System.out.println("SE VALIDÓ PARAMETRO");
                    JFrame_Facturar jf = new JFrame_Facturar(productosXFacturar, usuario, cliente, getThis());
                    jf.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Parece que el código se está ejecutando dos veces cuan presiono una tecla.

CONSOLA al teclear la tecla esc una sola vez:

EVENTO : postProcessKeyEvent
SE TECLEÓ ESC
SE VALIDÓ PARAMETRO
EVENTO : postProcessKeyEvent
EVENTO : postProcessKeyEvent
SE TECLEÓ ESC
SE VALIDÓ PARAMETRO

Comment: Podrías intentar imprimir por pantalla en distintos puntos de tu código, o bien probando debugear con breakpoints, para tener mayor claridad de lo que esta ocurriendo cuando presionas ESC.

Comment: Se editó la pregunta con los comentarios y las salidas por consola

Answer (score 0):

A decir verdad, no estoy muy familiarizado con AWT, pero basándome en algunos ejemplos que encontré en [ProgramCreek](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=java.awt.KeyEventPostProcessor), aparentemente en tu código no se consume el evento.

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().
        addKeyEventPostProcessor(new KeyEventPostProcessor() {
            public boolean postProcessKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
                Component c = e.getComponent();

                if ((!(c instanceof JComponent) ||
                     (c != null && !c.isEnabled())) &&
                        JComponent.KeyboardState.shouldProcess(e) &&
                        SwingUtilities.processKeyBindings(e)) {
                    e.consume(); // se consume el evento
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Esto puede provocar que al liberar la tecla se genere otro evento y, por lo tanto, se abra una nueva ventana.

Espero que sirva, saludos.